# Calling a JavaScript function when a button is clicked in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I wrote a simple JavaScript code that allows people to enter a number and it should return either FizzBuzz, Fizz, Buzz or just the number if it did not meet the conditions of the FizzBuzz game. I then tried to create a button in HTML with the following code:

```
<button onclick="fBCalc(prompt("Enter a number!"))">FizzBuzz</button>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<input type="button" name="FizzBuzz" value="FizzBuzz" onClick="fBCalc(prompt("Enter a number!"))" />
```

Both methods did not work. I have searched Google for an answer but I have tried them and nothing happens when I click the button. I made sure that the function was called correctly. This works without the button so I do not know why it shouldn't work with a button. Unless a button is unable to prompt o.o. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Here is a pastebin to my full HTML code: http://pastebin.com/YPGdbTVQ

Comment: I'm sensing a disturbance in your copy-paste. Try again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't pasted your code properly here, but I did spy what I suspect is your issue on your Pastebin:

```
<button onclick="fBCalc(prompt("Enter a number!"))">FizzBuzz</button>
```

You can't put quotes inside of quotes the way you have here, because the browser can't figure out which ones do what. Try swapping the inner quotes with single-quotes:

```
 <button onclick="fBCalc(prompt('Enter a number!'))">FizzBuzz</button>
```

Coincidentally, good luck with your grades! ;)

Comment: Wow! That was it. I totally forgot that I couldn't use the double quotation marks inside another double quotation mark. I will keep that in mind for the future :).

Comment: No worries. I'm a professional (allegedly) and I catch myself doing that a depressing amount of the time. All I can suggest is __make sure you use an editor with text highlighting__ - it'll catch stuff like this by messing up the highlight.

Comment: Yeah, I use Notepad++ and thought the highlighting was a bit weird.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it takes a while to be able to intuit what's actually wrong - especially early on, EVERYTHING makes your brain go "meeeeaaaaaghiwannawatchTV."

Comment: Yeah.. I am kind of struggling with objects and methods atm :(. Would you happen to know how I can easily learn this?

Comment: It's highly dependent on what language you're learning. If it's JavaScript, try http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml but if you're unlucky enough to be focusing on PHP, uh, good luck. When you hit 20 reputation here on Stack, feel free to send me a chat if you've got more questions. And protip: you can get more rep by accepting the answer. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am still new to JavaScript and this website.  People on this website are really helpful and gives me motivation to fully master this! :).

Answer (score 0):

you cant put double quotes inside double quotes, so make your code like this

```
<button onclick="fBCalc(prompt('Enter a number!'))">FizzBuzz</button>
```